# Как изменить значение WSA_MAXIMUM_WAIT_EVENTS?

Tags: c++, c, windows

Например для `FD_SET` значение задается через `FD_SETSIZE`. А как изменить значение константы `WSA_MAXIMUM_WAIT_EVENTS`?

Comment: возможно, будет полезно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/700653/winapi-tcp-port-mapper#comment1041328_700685

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак, это же константа =)

Но можно обойти данное ограничение.`WaitForMultipleObjects` / `WSAaitForMultipleEvents` может поддерживать только `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS / WSA_MAXIMUM_WAIT_EVENTS`, которые равны 64. Поэтому для каждого потока, который вызывает `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents`, модель ввода-вывода может поддерживать только до 64 сокетов единовременно. Если вы хотите, чтобы эта модель управляла более чем 64 сокетами единовременно, вы должны создать дополнительные рабочие потоки, чтобы ждать больше объектов событий.